# How to Validate Phone Number format

Tags: android, regex, validation

i am about to create a validation for phone number format..The format is 10 digit including the  plus sign eg:+0133999504. Even though I have declare the pattern which is I try to disallow the "-" symbol or any other characters, but the validation is not working. Any other Idea or solution?

```
1st I declared the string regex:

String PhoneNo;
String PhoneNo_PATTERN ="[\\+]\\d{3}\\d{7}";

2nd I make a if..else statement:
 {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PhoneNo_PATTERN);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(PhoneNo);
                    if (!matcher.matches()) 
                    {
                    inputemergencyContactNo.setError("Please enter Emergency Contact No");
                    }
                    else{
                    Toast.makeText(RiderProfile.this, "Please filled in All field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not remove all non-digits and then count the digits left and put the plus back in later? This allows users the freedom to fill out their phone number anyway they want...

```
String PhoneNo = "+123-456 7890";
String Regex = "[^\\d]";
String PhoneDigits = PhoneNo.replaceAll(Regex, "");
if (PhoneDigits.length()!=10)  
{
    // error message
}
else
{
    PhoneNo = "+";
    PhoneNo = PhoneNo.concat(PhoneDigits); // adding the plus sign

    // validation successful  

}
```

If your app is intended for international use replace

```
if (!PhoneDigits.length()!=10)
```

with

```
if(PhoneDigits.length() < 6 || PhoneDigits.length() > 13)
```

as Fatti Khan suggested.

---

To apply this in the code you posted at [Android EditText Validation and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265843/android-edittext-validation-and-regex) first include this method in your public class or the class containing onClick():

```
public boolean validateNumber(String S) {
    String Regex = "[^\\d]";
    String PhoneDigits = S.replaceAll(Regex, "");
    return (PhoneDigits.length()!=10);
}
```

And include this method in the CreateNewRider class:

```
protected String tidyNumber(String S) {
    String Regex = "[^\\d]";
    String PhoneDigits = S.replaceAll(Regex, "");
    String Plus = "+";
    return Plus.concat(PhoneDigits);
}
```

This is where the validation happens...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Boolean b = false;
    if(inputfullname.getText().toString().equals("")) b = true;

    else if(... // do this for all fields

    else if(inputmobileNo.getText().toString().equals("")) b=true;
    else if(inputemergencyContactNo.getText().toString().equals("")) b=true;
    else {
        if(validateNumber( inputmobileNo.getText().toString() ) 
            Toast.makeText(RiderProfile.this, "Invalid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        else if(validateNumber( inputemergencyContactNo.getText().toString() ) 
            Toast.makeText(RiderProfile.this, "Invalid emergency contact number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            // Validation succesful

            new CreateNewRider().execute();

        }   
    }
    if(b) Toast.makeText(RiderProfile.this, "Please filled in All field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And then use tidyNumber() in the CreateNewRider class:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String fullname= inputfullname.getText().toString();
        String IC= inputIC.getText().toString();
        String mobileNo= tidyNumber( inputmobileNo.getText().toString() );
        String emergencyContactName= inputemergencyContactName.getText().toString() );
        String emergencyContactNo= tidyNumber( inputemergencyContactNo.getText().toString() );

        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea n solution..i will try to insert to my coding..tq so much..

Comment: I already tried ur coding but still not working..Is it possible if i showed to you my full coding?

Comment: You don't need to show your full code but a bit more around the place where you pasted this in would help. It would also help to know what exact error/debug messages you get...

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!its work for my no phone format..finally..thank you for your helps..heads uP!!!!

Comment: Tq so much!!!its for now!!!credit and Heads UP to u!!!finally it is work..seriously.tq so much for helping me..@M'431

Answer (score 4):

Given the rules you specified:

upto length 13 and including character + infront.

(and also incorporating the min length of 10 in your code)

You're going to want a regex that looks like this:

```
^\+[0-9]{10,13}$
```

With the min and max lengths encoded in the regex, you can drop those conditions from your if() block.

Off topic: I'd suggest that a range of 10 - 13 is too limiting for an international phone number field; you're almost certain to find valid numbers that are both longer and shorter than this. I'd suggest a range of 8 - 20 to be safe.

[EDIT] OP states the above regex doesn't work due to the escape sequence. Not sure why, but an alternative would be:

```
^[+][0-9]{10,13}$
```

[EDIT 2] OP now adds that the + sign should be optional. In this case, the regex needs a question mark after the +, so the example above would now look like this:

```
^[+]?[0-9]{10,13}$
```

---

For Valid Mobile You need to consider 7 digit to 13 digit because some country have 7 digit mobile number . Also we can not check like mobile number must starts with 9 or 8 or anything..

For mobile number I used this this Function

```
private boolean isValidMobile(String phone2) 
{
    boolean check;
    if(phone2.length() < 6 || phone2.length() > 13)
    {
        check = false;
        txtPhone.setError("Not Valid Number");
    }
    else
    {
        check = true;
    }
    return check;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^[\\+]\\d{3}\\d{7}$
```

Use anchors to limit the match.

`^` => start of match

`$`=> end of match

Answer (score 0):

```
To validate India's mobile number.

Your edit text input 
edt_mobile.text.toString().trim()

Number validation method

    fun isValidMobile(phone: String): Boolean {
                return phone.matches(Constants.REGEX_MOBILE.toRegex()) && phone.trim().length == 10
      }

Regression expression 



 const val REGEX_MOBILE = "^[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}\$"
```